# Singleton not initializing correctly

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I have the following code that I am calling using this statement: SQLiteDB *db = [[[SQLiteDB alloc] init] autorelease];

The problem is "sharedSQLiteDB" is not being called, but rather "allocWithZone" is, and therefore "checkIfDatabaseExists" is not being called, which is where the database is created.

I don't understand why... (i.e. what am I doing wrong?)

```
#import "SQLiteDB.h"

static SQLiteDB *sharedSQLiteDB = nil;  //  makes this a singleton class

@implementation SQLiteDB

@synthesize searchPaths, documentPath, databasePath, cDatabasePath;

#pragma mark Singleton Methods

+ (SQLiteDB *) sharedSQLiteDB  {

    if(!sharedSQLiteDB)  {
        sharedSQLiteDB = [[SQLiteDB alloc] init];
        [sharedSQLiteDB checkIfDatabaseExists];  //  check to see if d/b exists
    }
    return sharedSQLiteDB;
}   

+(id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone  {  //  makes sure another instance is not allocated
    if(!sharedSQLiteDB)  {
        sharedSQLiteDB = [super allocWithZone:zone];
        return  sharedSQLiteDB;
    }
    else {
        return nil;
    }
}   

-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone  {
    return self;
}

-(void) release  {
    //  no-op
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't executing your `+ (SQLiteDB *) sharedSQLiteDB` method because you're not actually calling that method anywhere.

As you've seen, when you call `[[SQLiteDB alloc] init]`, the `allocWithZone` method is called.

Change your call to be `SQLiteDB *db = [SQLiteDB sharedSQLiteDB]`, which will call your `checkIfDatabaseExists` method in this case.  However, if `[[SQLiteDB alloc] init]` is called somewhere else, then the `checkIfDatabaseExists` method call will still be skipped.

Maybe consider moving the `checkIfDatabaseExists` method into an `init` method so that it will be called for both your singleton method and your `allocWithZone`.

Answer (score 1):

In the singleton pattern your use pattern should be:

```
SQLiteDB* db = [SQLiteDB sharedSQLiteDB];
```

They way you are calling it doesn't fit the singelton pattern. All access should be through your sharedSQLiteDB message.

In other words you shouldn't be initializing via typical Cocoa patterns (SQLiteDB *db = [[[SQLiteDB alloc] init] autorelease]; is incorrect and full of problems) outside the scope of the class.

In a singleton using the default initialization pattern for the language (alloc/init for ObjC or the default constructor for C++) should generate a compile time error message since the constructor/init method should be protected.

See the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) entry. consult the [Design Pattern](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) C++ bible. There is even a version for [Cocoa](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321535022)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I don't see any error...
However I post the code I used to create a Singleton. It's from a source that now I don't remember the link... it's not my code.

```
static DataManager *_instance;

@implementation DataManager

+ (DataManager*)sharedInstance
{
    @synchronized(self) {

        if (_instance == nil) {

            _instance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];

            // Allocate/initialize any member variables of the singleton class her
            // example
    //_instance.member = @"";
        }
    }
    return _instance;
}

#pragma mark Singleton Methods

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{   
    return [[self sharedInstance]retain];   
}


- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    return self;    
}

- (id)retain
{   
    return self;    
}

- (unsigned)retainCount
{
    return NSUIntegerMax;  //denotes an object that cannot be released
}

- (void)release
{
    //do nothing
}

- (id)autorelease
{
    return self;    
}
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using the SyntesizeSingleton header file first created by Matt Gallagher.

Find the latest version (that I know about) here:

https://github.com/cjhanson/Objective-C-Optimized-Singleton

It makes creating a singleton dead simple.

Here's an example header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Example : NSObject {}
+(Example*)sharedExample;
@end
```

And the corresponding .m:

```
#import "FMUser.h"
#import "SynthesizeSingleton.h"
@implementation Example
SYNTHESIZE_SINGLETON_FOR_CLASS(Example);
@end
```

`[Example sharedExample]` is created for you. It's pretty sweet.